# Find the last substring after a character

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I know many ways how to find a substring: from start index to end index, between characters etc., but I have a problem which I don't know how to solve:
I have a string like for example a path: `folder1/folder2/folder3/new_folder/image.jpg`
and the second path: `folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/image2.png`

And from this paths I want to take only the last parts: `image.jpg` and `image2.png`. How can I take a substring if I don't know when it starts (I don't know the index, but I can suppose that it will be after last `/` character), if many times one character repeats (`/`) and the extensions are different (`.jpg` and `.png` and even other)?

Comment: Did  you want `image.png` or `image2.png`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Of course I wanted image2.png ;)

Answer (score 41):

Use [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) instead and not worry about the details.

`os.path.basename()` returns the filename portion of your path:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basename('folder1/folder2/folder3/new_folder/image.jpg')
'image.jpg'
```

For a more generic string splitting problem, you can use [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) to split a string on a given character sequence *counting from the end*:

```
>>> 'foo:bar:baz'.rpartition(':')
('foo:bar', ':', 'baz')
>>> 'foo:bar:baz'.rpartition(':')[-1]
'baz'
```

and with [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) you can split multiple times up to a limit, again from the end:

```
>>> 'foo:bar:baz:spam:eggs'.rsplit(':', 3)
['foo:bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

Last but not least, you could use [`str.rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) to find just the index of a substring, searching from the end:

```
>>> 'foo:bar:baz'.rfind(':')
7
```

Answer (score 23):

You can do this as well -

```
str_mine = 'folder1/folder2/folder3/new_folder/image.jpg'    
print str_mine.split('/')[-1]

>> image.png
```

Answer (score 6):

you can do this split on last occurrence

```
my_string='folder1/folder2/folder3/new_folder/image2.png'
print(my_string.rsplit("/",1)[1])
output:-
image2.png
```

Comment: Does this answer add any value than the same answer posted an year ago?

Comment: @Darpan Do you mean [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43630760/6045800) (suggesting `split('/')[-1]`)? Yes it adds alot. While your answer splits the whole string and takes the last element, this only splits once from the right. A bit more efficient. Even more efficient would be to use `rpartition`...

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(.*?)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+?\.\w+)")
y = pattern.match(x).groups()
print y[1]
```

No length constraints.